# How am I saving with a null user ID in a Django view?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a Django view that is supposed to save a CalendarEvent (a model instance) with three fields set, including the current user's profile object. The views are protected by @login_required, and I logged in as the superuser, then called a view getting the error:

```
    /Users/jonathan/pim/../pim/pim_calendar/views.py in save_calendar
            date_padding = ''
        regexp = weekday + ' ' + month + ' ' + date_padding + date + \
          ' ..:..:.. ... ' + year
        event = pim_calendar.models.CalendarEvent()
        event.when = regexp
        event.description = description
        event.user = request.user.get_profile()
        event.save()
```

in the traceback. (request.user should be me logged in as the superuser.)

The error I'm getting is:

```
IntegrityError at /save_calendar
pim_calendar_calendarevent.userprofile_id may not be NULL
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/save_calendar
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
pim_calendar_calendarevent.userprofile_id may not be NULL
Exception Location: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 234
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.0
Python Path:    
['/Users/jonathan/pim',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.14-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-0.8.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info']
Server time:    Thu, 16 Feb 2012 15:00:21 -0600
```

If I add, before the event.save() call,

```
        print repr(event.user)
```

the console displays, """<UserProfile: UserProfile object>""" before the crash on IntegrityError.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

From the error message it looks like instead of:

```
    event.user = request.user.get_profile()
```

You should be calling this:

```
    event.userprofile = request.user.get_profile()
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @jkbr said, you might want to consider not saving the UserProfile reference in the CalendarEvent object. Instead, just save the user associated with the CalendarEvent, then access the UserProfile by:

```
# Save event
event = pim_calendar.models.CalendarEvent()
event.user = request.user
event.user.save()

# Access the profile
event = CalendarEvent.objects.get(...)
the_userprofile = event.user.get_profile()
```